# Export to Excel in Admin on rest ListView

Tags: excel, admin-on-rest

I have an AdminOnRest front end App where I have a few Grids which display the data. I wanted to have an export option on the form that will allow me to export the data to an excel file. I searched Stack Overflow but could not find a suitable answer for it.

I know I need to add a custom button to export data but since I am new to AOR, I am not sure what's the right way to do it.

Comment: have you read the documentation about custom buttons yet ?

Comment: I didnt find the documentation for that in AOR. Can u help? @Gildas

Comment: Can you be more specific about your issue ? Are struggling to add a custom button or to export data for excel ?

Comment: I have a listView with the data populated. I want to add a button on the listView that will export that data to excel.